# Which is the order of filling a triangular matrix?

Tags: c, algorithm, big-o

I'm filling a lower triangular matrix like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        l[i][j] = j + 1;
}
```

And I want to calculate the order of the code in Big O notation but I'm really bad. If it was a regular matrix it would be O(n²) but in this case I'm not sure if it's O(nlog(n)) or something like that.

Comment: Since a triangular matrix, it would have (n²/2) entries which is still O(n²)

Comment: So it doesn't matter if I also fill the upper triangle with zeros? It will have the same order? Thank you! :)

Comment: It will have the same order. But it doesn't mean they will take the same time to execute. No point filling zeroes if it is unwanted

Comment: Great, thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically (but not always) one loop nested in another will cause O(N²).

Think about it, the inner loop is executed `i` times, for each value of `j`. The outer loop is executed `size` times.

This comes out to be 1/2 of N^2, which is still O(N^2)